# Question about claw-free graphs

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-theory, graph-algorithms, planar-graphs

Let $G$ be a claw-free graph, and let $x,y,z,u$ be distinct vertices of $G$. Is the following possible in $G$ ?
There are three **induced** paths through $u$: between $y$ and $z$ (i.e., $y \rightsquigarrow u \rightsquigarrow z$), between $x$ and $z$ (i.e., $x \rightsquigarrow u \rightsquigarrow z$), and between $x$ and $y$ (i.e., $x \rightsquigarrow u \rightsquigarrow y$).

It seems that this is impossible in a claw-free graph...
Would appreciate any help with a refutation, or perhaps insights to a proof.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the graph $G = (V,E)$ with vertex set $V=\{a,b,c,d,x,y,z,u\}$ and edge set $E=\{ac,bd,au,bu,cu,du,ax,bx,cy,dz\}$. Then, if I am not mistaken, $x,b,u,c,y$ is an induced path through $u$ between $x$ and $y$, $x,a,u,d,z$ is an induced path through $u$ between $x$ and $z$, and $y,b,u,d,z$ is an induced path through $u$ between $y$ and $z$. However, $G$ is claw-free.